# How do I run a process in a UWP before displaying app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've completed a winform project that handles a uri scheme (TEL:)

I'm now trying to do the same in UWP. I've successfully got the app launching on TEL activation.

How do I stop the app showing when its run with arguments? Run silent.

The app runs a task and closes. There is no need for the UI unless the user hasn't done the first time set up or there is an error.

I've been looking into prelaunch but before painting myself into a corner I wanted to ask a more experienced user what the best practice is as I would like to publish this application and follow best practice.

I've checked similar questions but they were after a background service.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain tel activation?

Comment: just like mailto: opens outlook if a user clicks a tel: link a simply want to run a process.

Comment: So, you just want to launch your uwp app without UI right?

Comment: Yes there is a process that is run that requires no UI is this possible while staying within Microsoft guidelines?

Comment: Unfortunately, UWP is not support no- UI running, and there is not such background task  trigger for detecting tel: launch.

Comment: Can i safely run a exe from inside my own app directory? Doesn't need administrator rights

Comment: You could use `FullTrustProcessLauncher` to launch exe file without administrator, for more please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher?view=winrt-18362) .

Answer (score 1):

Answer thanks to Nico Zhu.

Can not launch an app without displaying UI but it is possible to use 'FullTrustProcessLauncher' to run an exe instead.

[More information on this can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher?view=winrt-18362https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher?view=winrt-18362)